# Grave accent ` symbol showing error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

my code is working fine in chrome but in IE it's showing an error invalid character is there any other method to do this I tried using single/double quotes still not working in IE as well in IE. Can anyone suggest me how to do.
`` $(`.${divClass}`) `` from here getting an error.

```js
$(".benefits").click(function() {
  let otherButtons = $(".benefits").not($(this));
  otherButtons.siblings(".card-body").addClass("noDisplay");
  otherButtons.parent().removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  $('.benefits-wrap').children('div').addClass("noDisplay");
  let divClass = $(this).data('div');
  $(`.${divClass}`).toggleClass("noDisplay");
});
```

```css
.benefits-slideDiv1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.benefits-slideDiv2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.benefits-slideDiv3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.benefits-slideDiv4 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}

div#accordionExample {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.benefits-wrap {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
}

.benefits-acc.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.benefits-acc.active h3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion nav" id="accordionExample" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <div class="benefits-acc active">
    <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide1" data-div="benefits-slideDiv1">
      <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
    </button>
    <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv1">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="benefits-acc">
  <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide2" data-div="benefits-slideDiv2">
    <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
  </button>
  <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv2 noDisplay">
    <p>content 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="benefits-acc">
  <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide3" data-div="benefits-slideDiv3">
    <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
  </button>
  <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv3 noDisplay">
    <p>content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="benefits-acc">
  <button class="benefits d-flex benefits-slide4" data-div="benefits-slideDiv4">
    <h3 class="pl-3">Personalized health journey</h3>
  </button>
  <div class="card-body benefits-slideDiv4 noDisplay">
    <p>content 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="benefits-wrap">
  <h3>Second content block</h3>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv1"> Second content 1</div>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv2 noDisplay">Second content 2</div>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv3 noDisplay">Second content 3</div>
  <div class="benefits-slideDiv4 noDisplay">Second content 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That symbol is used to denote a [Template Literal string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which is unsupported in IE, hence the error you're seeing.

To fix this use traditional string concatenation:

```
$('.' + divClass).toggleClass("noDisplay");
```